# Google shows IP instead of domain

Tags: seo, google-search-console, domains, google-search

I've tried breaking my problem down into some smaller stuff that I asked here but I couldn't figure it out so I am looking for a complete solution now. Google is showing my website's IP address https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx instead of my domain. Since it is https, I can't redirect to my domain because the certificate check fails before a redirect can be made. I have already redirected http ip address to my domain. How do I make my domain show up instead of IP address?

From google search console everything seems to be ok for my domain: the last crawl was a day ago, indexing and crawling is allowed, and it is the google selected canonical.

If I search site:mydomain.xxx, it shows up on google but not bing. I only care about google though, but I am a little worried about why it doesn't show up on bing.

There is a pretty similar-title question but the issue was due to redirecting to the IP from domain, which I am not doing.

I can provide my IP and domain if you want but I'm scared this will be deleted for being self promotional.

Comment: Google takes a few weeks to update the search results after you make changes to your site.  From the timing of the other questions, I don't think it has been that long yet, has it?

Comment: oh its only been 1 week. Is there some way to speed that up? they disabled the request crawl thing, I tried submitting a txt sitemap but it didn't work

Comment: Google moves at its own speed.  All you can do is wait for it.   Google could start changing some URLs over any day now.  It will do your most popular (highest pagerank) pages first.  It could take months for Google to change every single one of your pages.